# How can i set a backgroung-image on the start site in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am very new to Angular (Angular 12) . I'm trying to build a small frontend and I'm still a couple of things not really clear.First I created a component for the header and integrated it into my app.component. So far so good. Next I wanted to display a background image on the start page.

To integrate the background image I created a body and div in the app.component.html where the image should be loaded.

```
<div class="header-container">
  <app-header></app-header>
</div>
<body>
  <div class="bg">
  </div>
</body>
```

Next I have adjusted my app.component.css accordingly.

```
.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("../assets/img/writing-desk.jpg");
  
    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;
  
    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

in the last step i added my style url in the app.components.ts.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Frontend-LiveOps';
}
```

Problem: The backgroud image is not displayed to me. Also no error message appears in the console of VSCode and also not in the console of Chrome.

But when I display the source code in Chrome, the source code of the index.html is displayed.

What I don't understand is why I created the header in app.component.html for example and the header is displayed but the background image is not. the app.component is the same as my landing page, isn't it? But why is the source code of the index.html shown to me?

Does anyone have a good description (link, video, etc) for how the structure of Angular works and where do I have to pack my background image so that it is displayed when starting the app?

Comment: Try adding the `bg` class to the `html` or `body` tags. Also check each element with Chrome dev tools to see where the class is and if maybe the property is overwritten by another class.

Comment: For starters the elements you're declaring outside of your `body` tag are invalid markup. If you're just trying to put a background on the body you don't need additional elements anyway and can just do your css like `body { background: url("../assets/img/writing-desk.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover }` but that assumes your relative path to the image is correct to find the image.

Answer (score 1):

It has no thing to do with angular. Applying height in % will look into its parent's height and in your case it doesn't have one.

When ever you wanted a tag to appear as box make sure you have a height and width.